# Pause and resume media player when streaming video

Tags: android, video, android-mediaplayer

In my application I play HLS video using the MediaPlayer and SurfaceHolder classes.
Everything works fine except for when a user leaves leaves the player and then returns.

From logging I can tell that when the user returns to my VideoPlayerActivity the MediaPlayer object is still around and the progress of the video is saved. If I simply try to start the video again I get this message :

```
[SurfaceView] queueBuffer: SurfaceTexture has been abandoned!
E/SurfaceTextureClient(128): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -19
```

I understand this is because the SurfaceHolder used by the MediaPlayer is no longer around (I know it's gets destroyed in the OnStop state of the activity).

My question is if there is any way to use the same MediaPlayer object and attach a new surface to it?